# Html Formatting Grid View

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to format my grid view so it looks like the following:

[image]

so instead of looking like a table it has 2 columns and 3 rows. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider switching your server control to an `<asp:ListView>`. This gives you granular control over your markup, compared to a gridview.

Here's a great [ListView tutortial by the Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use an `asp:ListView` instead. It allows for template items, meaning you can specify the HTML yourself while still having much of the list-type functionality that, say, an `asp:Repeater` would lack.

The listview was new to .NET 3.5, though, so if you are using an older version, I would just use the repeater. Both allow you to specify your own markup, which you will need to do to render your items as you have them shown above.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use a `asp:Repeater` control as that gives you greater control over the html you want to display.

Answer (score 1):

If the use of a GridView is mandatory, you can do this:

```
<h2>
    GridView
</h2>
<asp:GridView id="MyList" CssClass="Grid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="item_container">
                    <div class="image_container">
                        <asp:Image ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>' runat="server"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="link_text_container">
                        <asp:HyperLink Text="Some Link" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Link") %>' runat="server" /><br />
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Text") %>' runat="server" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="datetime_container">
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("DateTime") %>' runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Only for demonstration purposes, in code behind you can do this:

```
public class Item
{
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string DateTime { get; set; }
}

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Item[] items = new Item[5]{ new Item()
                                        {
                                            ImageUrl="img/imageplaceholder.jpg",
                                            Link="~/somelink1.html",
                                            Text="Some Text 1",
                                            DateTime=DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
                                        }, 
                                    new Item()
                                        {
                                            ImageUrl="img/imageplaceholder.jpg",
                                            Link="~/somelink2.html",
                                            Text="Some Text 2",
                                            DateTime=DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
                                        }, 
                                    new Item()
                                        {
                                            ImageUrl="img/imageplaceholder.jpg",
                                            Link="~/somelink3.html",
                                            Text="Some Text 3",
                                            DateTime=DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
                                        }, 
                                    new Item()
                                        {
                                            ImageUrl="img/imageplaceholder.jpg",
                                            Link="~/somelink4.html",
                                            Text="Some Text 4",
                                            DateTime=DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
                                        }, 
                                    new Item()
                                        {
                                            ImageUrl="img/imageplaceholder.jpg",
                                            Link="~/somelink5.html",
                                            Text="Some Text 5",
                                            DateTime=DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
                                        }
                                  };

            MyList.DataSource = items;
            MyList.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

And use the following CSS:

```
table
{
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
}

.item_container
{
    width: 700px;
    background-color:#FFE5FF;
}

.image_container
{
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}

.link_text_container
{
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
    background-color:#E5FFF2;
}

.datetime_container
{
    width: 100%;
    clear:both;
    background-color:#B3ECFF;
}
```

It will produce the desired layout with a GridView, but indeed, the asp:ListView is a better choice.

[GridView Layout http://i53.tinypic.com/2l5l5s.jpg](http://i53.tinypic.com/2l5l5s.jpg)